# i want a git "sticky" file that stays in my working copy and never updates

Tags: git

i have a git stash which contains a single file, which cannot be version controlled in the central repository (file is generated) but i want to cache locally in version control for convenience. right now i have it in a git stash but that lends itself to being accidentally staged.

i also have a second file (eclipse's .classpath) which IS under master version control but i make local modifications for my own convenience. i want similar sticky functionality with git so i don't accidentally commit this file, but have it here with my local modifications and can merge against upstream changes as well.

how can i accomplish this sort of "sticky" file?

Answer (score 3):

Add it to your .gitignore file.

Comment: You should mention: If you add a file to `.gitignore` it is just ignored from `git add` (as long as you dont add it with the `-f` option). So the "master file" in the main repo is not touch (especially its not removed).

Comment: It also doesn't come up as an untracked file in git status. And, because it is untracked it remains unchanged when switching branches, changes aren't merged, changes don't prevent switching branches, merging, or rebasing…